# Moving Row in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, function, google-sheets

I've been tasked to correct a mass of broken functions used by our team in Google Sheets. The creator left no notes and is no longer with the company. The last issue that I've attempted correcting has been throwing me for a loop the previous few days and I need a second pair of eyes to help identify what is going on.

### Example file:

[Generic Test File Found Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16phg5ySFQ4N9nW6Cvxd3R0Lw5Wrj8EcMUXuZf6q72-8/edit?usp=sharing)

### Purpose:

Our Managers keep track of their internal quality check (QC) items through a tracker, where a user will "submit" their work to be reviewed by another. This process involves a "Peer" and a "Final" QC. In order to help us better track items to QC, and to review team and individual accuracy, we have created the a Google Sheet similar to the referenced sheet above.

### Code:

```
function moveRow(rowNum, fromSheet, toSheet) {
      var tolastRow = toSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var rowData = fromSheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, 14);
      rowData.copyTo(toSheet.getRange(tolastRow, 1, 1, 14), {contentsOnly: true});
      fromSheet.deleteRow(rowNum);
  var fromlastRow = fromSheet.getLastRow();
      fromSheet.insertRowBefore(fromlastRow+1);
      fromSheet.getRange(fromlastRow+2, 1, 1, 14).copyTo(fromSheet.getRange(fromlastRow+1, 1, 1, 14));
  return tolastRow

}

function checkSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var peerSheets = ss.getSheetByName('Peer');
  var finalSheets = ss.getSheetByName('Final');
  var com = ss.getSheetByName('Complete');
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var date = new Date();
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, 'MM/dd/yy')

  for(i=0; i<peerSheets.length; i++){
    var status = peerSheets[i].getRange("F:F").getValues();
    var lastStatus = status.filter(String).length;
    for(k=2; k<=lastStatus; k++){
      if(peerSheets[i].getRange(k, 6).getValue() == 'Submit to Final') {
        var lastRow = moveRow(k, peerSheets[i], finalSheets[i]);
        finalSheets[i].getRange(lastRow, 6).setValue('New');
        finalSheets[i].getRange(lastRow,14).setValue(finalSheets[i].getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue());
        finalSheets[i].getRange(lastRow, 2).clearContent();
        k = k-1;
      }
    }
    for(k=2; k<=finalSheets[i].getLastRow(); k++){
      if(finalSheets[i].getRange(k, 6).getValue() == 'Complete'){
        var lastRow = moveRow(k, finalSheets[i],com);
        com.getRange(lastRow, 15).setValue(d);
        k = k-1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Expectations:

When a person is done with their work, they will mark the cell in the column F in the Peer / Final tabs which should trigger the function to move that row into the next corresponding tab (in order Peer > Final > Complete).

### Error:

I receive a: "TypeError: Cannot call method "getLastRow" of undefined. (line 2)" error in the script editor when I go to run the script.

How do I correct this error and get this function to work properly?

Comment: This doesn't help you, sorry, but does your company know there are a lot of free issue trackers that will do a much better job than a roll-your-own solution?

Comment: @StephenP Thank you for your concern. There are larger issues that our companies resources are tackling and focusing their efforts on. This is a smaller side project that our team is trying to tackle, and using the resources we have available, this is the best solution for our needs, and we are wanting to pursue using it.

Comment: What function did you run? I think that when ``moveRow()`` is run, the error will occur. And when ``checkSheets()`` is run, ``for(i=0; i<peerSheets.length; i++){}`` is not used because ``peerSheets`` is not an array. I hope this information useful for you.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike! thank you for your input. With the peerSheets not being an array, how would you recommend us to proceed?